# Which calender is correct ? Poornimantha (month ending with poornima) or Amantha (month ending with Amavasya)?

Tags: panchang

Which calender is correct ? Poornimantha (month ending with poornima) or Amantha (month ending with Amavasya) ?

Comment: Both are correct..some geography follows one some other...

Comment: yes both are correct.. its like asking days calculate only with sunlight or days can also calculated with night time.. both are correct but panchanga is triganitha is correct all are incorrect because they didnt predict eclipse correctly

Comment: OK. Thanks for the answers. We celebrate certain months like Karthik and Shraavan. I see these months are celebrated at different days in Bengal compared to Telangana where I live.....